# Lost pointer/reference to splitViewController.viewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard

I have an app and whose root view is a split view.  Xcode 4.3, iOS 5.1, using storyboards, coreData and ARC.

The split view contains a `viewController` (master VC on the left) and a `tabViewController` (detailVC on the right).

On the master VC, I have 4 different `UITableViewControllers` that slide in based on the cell that the user selects, a vanilla `UIViewController`, then another `UITableViewController`.  The drill down is: Login, select state, select county, select municipality, (all tableviews so far) then in the `UIView`, select some filtering, then (the last tableview) show all items.  It's a drill down to a location and as the user drills, the view controller at `index:0` on the detail side (which contains a map view) zooms in. (Hope that makes sense).

The last tableview on the left is populated with a bunch of items - and the detail view controller on the right is to show an annotated map of locations of the items in the left or, since it is a tabview, a detail listing of all the items details.

All along the way (during drill down on the left side) I set `self.mapViewController = (MapViewController *) [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];` so that I can pass stuff to the map and when something new is passed (i.e. `-(void)setLocationItem:(id)newLocationItem)`) the map will configView with the new item.

Everything works great during the drill down - user select state, county, municipality and the detail map view  zooms in closer and closer, but when we get to the tableview that lists all of the items, I find that `self.splitViewController.viewControllers` (for that view controller) is empty!  I can't set the detail or map view controller to pass a property (the item I want to zoom to or show details for).

I should also mention that it all worked great when I was using core data and a `managedObjectContext` - now I'm dealing with a web service and am no longer (for this fork of the code) passing around a managed Object - just setting a property on the next view that comes along.